# Polyglossia doesn't accent limits (lím) in Spanish

Tags: xetex, polyglossia, spanish

I'm currently writing a text in Spanish that includes limits and I have to use Times New Roman font, so I'm using XeTeX, and thus, Polyglossia.

The problem is: when writing the `\lim` command, the text displayed is "lim" and not "lím" (with accent mark) as is used in Spanish.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{spanish}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

Éste es el estilo textual: $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6} $,
y éste el estilo de visualización:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

That gives this result:

[image: Limits does not get accented]

Is there something I can do to overcome this issue? Must we consider it a bug?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. `\lim` is, for me, a mathematic notation and so shall not be "tranlated". Have you tried without Times New Roman to see if the result is the same?

Comment: @RomainPicot Indeed I have tried and the result is the same. Also, I must point out that "lím", in Spanish, stands for "límite", so it must be accented; moreover, while using PDFLaTeX with `babel` this is not an issue: "lim" gets correctly translated. P.S. Thank you for your welcome! :)

Comment: Perhaps a deliberate design by `polyglossia`. Someone with more knowledge about it may confirm (or say how to overcome it)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In my opinion, “lim” is a symbolic abbreviation for “limes” (Latin), just like “sin” is for “sinus”.

The fact that the word is translated in various languages doesn't mean the symbol should follow. So, in my opinion, using “lím” is plainly wrong, just like using “sen” as done by almost all Italian school books (later, students learn it's written “sin”).

Of course you're free not to follow this advice or, maybe, some authority (usually the thesis supervisor `;-)`) gently asks for the accent. With `babel` you get it, `polyglossia` doesn't impose it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{spanish}

\makeatletter
\appto\inlineextras@spanish{\renewcommand\lim{\qopname \relax m{lím}}}
\appto\blockextras@spanish{\renewcommand\lim{\qopname \relax m{lím}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Éste es el estilo textual: $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6} $, y
éste el estilo de visualización:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Although I differ, because I think one must adhere to the rules of style of any language ---as `babel` does---, I really appreciate your opinion (and be sure I'll be discussing this with my teacher). Thank you very much for your kind answer!

Comment: @EstebanMendoza You use Greek letters in math even if they are foreign to Spanish, don't you?

Comment: While I think you're right, we then must ask why does `babel` have used this notation for many years without complaints.

Comment: @EstebanMendoza The question *why does the lime operator have an accent?* appears quite often in the support places of this earth. `babel` also provides an option for that.