# (mód 1) is not copied correctly

Tags: fonts, symbols, languages, accents, characters

Please consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\selectlanguage{spanish}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
Works: áéà

Does not work: \(\pmod1\)
\end{document}
```

The `áéà` text is copied correctly, but if I try to copy **`(mód 1)`** it says: **`(m´od 1)`**.

Does anyone know why this happens? How is it solved?

Thanks!

Comment: Possibly a viewer problem.  Here it works fine (TL2018): https://hastebin.com/elulugejaw.shell

Comment: @HenriMenke possibly... It works fine with your link. Something similar happens to me with the `listings` package. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: with recent miktex i obtain your result. for correct vowels in math operators names use `\usepackage[spanish, english]{babel}
\selectlanguage{spanish}`.

Comment: @Zarko thanks for your reply! I added `english` option but now it does not have accent, i.e. it displays as `(mod 1)` and copy as `(mod 1)` `:(((`.

Comment: @manooooh, hm, i obtain accent character in the first text line, and correct in the second line (when use option english in babel. something weird happens :-(

Comment: @Zarko yup, *very* weird. I have `enumerate` options (using my code) and the third level or something like that the enumeration format is `I), II), ...` (I would have liked them to appear in lowercase, but nvm). Anyway, when I add that option all the enumeration goes crazy and, for that example, the actual enumeration is `i), ii), ...`. Weeeeird.

Comment: At least partly this seems to be viewer dependent. I compiled your example with MikTeX's `pdflatex` (all packages updated yesterday) and got good copy text with SumatraPDF, but Adobe Reader gave me `(mod 1)`, Firefox, Chrome and Edge all said `(m ́od 1)`. (Of course this still shows that something is off, the consensus between viewers here is the wrong paste text, which is not good.)

Comment: @moewe a solution for an Adobe Reader user? Oh, it seems in most of viewers the text is wrong.

Comment: On the whole it is rather surprising that some viewers get it right. spanish.ldf uses an math accent here.

Comment: @manooooh `spanish.ldf` is the file read by `babel` that provides support for the Spanish language. This redefines `\pmod` to do `m\es@op@ac od` and `\es@op@ac o` basically does `\acute{o}`, which will *not* use a precomposed character, whence the issue you have.

Comment: As I say [elsewhere](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/282233/4427), “mod”, ”lim” and “sin” are *symbols*, not abbreviations. They come from the Latin name, so they should *never* bear accents. I know this position goes against established traditions, but they're wrong nonetheless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `babel` module `spanish.ldf` redefines `\pmod` to do `m\es@op@ac od` and `\es@op@ac` is essentially `\acute` (with a correction for `i` in order to use the dotless i).

At the expense of a new math group, you can do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\protected\def\es@op@ac#1{\csname math#1acute\endcsname}
\AtBeginDocument
 {%
  \DeclareSymbolFont{toneoperators}{T1}{\familydefault}{m}{n}%
  \SetSymbolFont{toneoperators}{bold}{T1}{\familydefault}{bx}{n}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\mathAacute}{\mathord}{toneoperators}{193}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\mathEacute}{\mathord}{toneoperators}{201}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\mathIacute}{\mathord}{toneoperators}{205}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\mathOacute}{\mathord}{toneoperators}{211}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\mathUacute}{\mathord}{toneoperators}{218}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\mathaacute}{\mathord}{toneoperators}{225}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\matheacute}{\mathord}{toneoperators}{233}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\mathiacute}{\mathord}{toneoperators}{237}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\mathoacute}{\mathord}{toneoperators}{243}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\mathuacute}{\mathord}{toneoperators}{250}%
 }%
\def\operator@font{\mathgroup\symtoneoperators}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

mód lím máx

$\mod\quad\lim\quad\max$

\end{document}
```

[image]