# Conflict with package newpxmath and \accentedoperators

Tags: babel, accents, spanish

Whenever I use the `\accentedoperators` command from `spanish`, `babel`, alongside the package `newpxmath`, the accents on math commands disappear. Not only that, dots on i's disappear as well.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish.noindentfirst,
%don't mind these, just playing with some options and solutions
    %mexico,
    %es-minimal,
    %es-noindentfirst,
    %mexico-com,
    %es-sloppy,
]{babel}
\accentedoperators
\decimalpoint

\usepackage{newpxtext}
\usepackage[varg]{newpxmath} %if you comment out this line, it works

\begin{document}

\chapter{}

These words should be accented: límite, gráfica, función. 

Both of these should use a decimal point: $2.099$ and 2.099.

These words need to be accented: $\lim$, $\max$, $\min$.
$$\lim f=\max g=\min h$$

Both of these should have angle quotes: "`John"', <<Juan>>.

\end{document}
```

[image]

This used to work until some time ago, I don't know exactly when it stopped.

Comment: You can use @egreg's patch from here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/448115/2388.

Comment: Confirmed, the patch works well (and the accented letters are also copied and pasted correctly). Beware that `$$` should not be used in LaTeX.

Comment: If you don't need to copy/paste the operators, a simpler solution is available, by add the following lines to your preamble: (first line) `\makeatletter` (second line) `\DeclareMathAccent{\TONEacute}{\mathord}{operators}{"13}` (third line) `\renewcommand{\es@op@ac}[1]{\TONEacute{\if i#1\dotlessi\else #1\fi}}` (fourth line) `\makeatother` Note: there is a single space in the four lines, namely between `\if` and `i`.

Comment: Thank you, I will be using the last fix, as I don't have (or I don't understand) what is the copy/paste problem.