# How can I write the Spanish 'lím' instead of 'lim'?

Tags: errors, compiling, accents, compilation-error, spanish

Consider:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}$

\end{document}
```

This creates the typical limit symbol when n goes to infinity. However this code no longer works when I try to typeset 'lím', which is how it is written in Spanish.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

$\displaystyle\lím_{n\to\infty}$

\end{document}
```

I get the error message `! Please use \mathaccent for accents in math mode.`. Despite trying to use the command it does not fix the issue.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

$\displaystyle\l\mathaccent{í}m_{n\to\infty}$

\end{document}
```

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

$\displaystyle\l\mathaccent{i}m_{n\to\infty}$

\end{document}
```

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: “lim” is a symbol, not an abbreviation. It entered the scene to stand for “limes”. Similarly for “max” and “min”. I regret that typographical traditions don’t care about history and meaning. In chemistry you don’t use “Hi” instead of “Fe” for iron.

Comment: @egreg Everything was so much easier in the Roman Empire.

Comment: Crosslink for polyglossia →[xetex - Polyglossia doesn't accent limits (lím) in Spanish - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/282229/polyglossia-doesnt-accent-limits-l%C3%ADm-in-spanish/282233#282233)

Comment: Wiktionary: *[lim](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lim#Translingual)* - *"Translingual. Symbol. 1. (mathematics) limit"*. Is "lím" for *[límite](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/l%C3%ADmite#Noun_2)*? [*lím* isn't listed](https://es.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?fulltext=Buscar&search=l%C3%ADm&title=Especial%3ABuscar&ns0=1).

Answer (score 31):

You can load `babel` with the [spanish](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/babel-spanish) option. It changes `\lim` and other math operators to their Spanish versions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\begin{document}

$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 19):

If, for some reason, you can't load the [babel](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/babel) package with the `spanish` option, you could redeclare the `\lim` macro as follows.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath} % for \DeclareMathOperator* macro
\let\lim\relax % release ("undefine") "\lim" as a macro name
\DeclareMathOperator*{\lim}{l\acute\i m}

\begin{document}
$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}$
\end{document}
```

For more information about creating accented characters in math and text mode see, e.g., [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/281887/5001) to the query [Trying to use `\~` to generate tilde symbol in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/281881/5001). (Shameless self-citation alert!)

Answer (score 14):

There is no “magic rule” that allows you to type `\lim` to get the standard symbol and `\lím` to get the accent.

The command `\lim` has its own definition that eventually produces “lim” in upright medium font face, with appropriate positioning of the subscript, depending on the current math style. If you type `\lím` you get the same as

```
\l ím
```

because `í` cannot (in `pdflatex`) be part of a control sequence name (OK, this is not the full truth, but it's enough for this case). The error you get is because TeX doesn't like `\l` (the command to get ł in text) in math mode. You'd get a different error message if you had

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

What you need is to *redefine* `\lim` to get the accent. But, if you write in Spanish, you should do

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
```

and the dreaded accents will appear.

Why “dreaded”? Because “lim” is *not* an abbreviation of a Spanish word, but started its life in mathematics from the Latin word *limes*. Similarly for other symbols.

Would you denote the iron element in chemistry with “Hi” instead of “Fe”? It's exactly the same. Symbols accepted in a scientific community are independent of the language.

This said, you can easily switch between the two possibilities.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % necessary for Spanish
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath} % necessary for math

%\unaccentedoperators

\begin{document}

$\lim$\par
$\limsup$\par
$\liminf$\par
$\max$\par
$\min$\par
$a\equiv b\pmod{n}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you uncomment the `\unaccentedoperators` line, you get

[image]

#### Unicode engines

If you use either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, you should use `fontspec` and remove `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, of course.

There's no point in having a preamble that “works” for 8-bit and Unicode engines, because it is essentially impossible to have a document that runs unchanged in both situations except, perhaps, for very simple documents.

Well, one could think to do something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{iftex}

\iftutex
  \usepackage{fontspec}
\else
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\fi

% other packages

%%% settings
\iftutex
  % settings for XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX
\else
  % settings for pdflatex
\fi

\ifluatex
  % settings for LuaLaTeX
\fi

\ifxetex
  % settings for XeTeX
\fi
```

For instance, font loading for XeLaTeX might be different from LuaLaTeX (there are keys specific for either engine). However, my experience is that this is hopeless in most cases.

More important is to see whether you can do something about `polyglossia` instead of `babel`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{amsmath} % necessary for math

\setmainlanguage[spanishoperators]{spanish}

\begin{document}

$\lim$\par
$\limsup$\par
$\liminf$\par
$\max$\par
$\min$\par
$a\equiv b\pmod{n}$

\end{document}
```

Here's an extract of the documentation to see what values `spanishoperator` can receive.

[image]

Comment: I think I’ll start denoting it by “græn” when writing in Danish, just to see people’s faces. `;-)`

Comment: I very much doubt that the OP is in a position to change the practices of Spanish-language publications, so the lengthy rant about how you believe accent marks shouldn't be used is irrelevant and should be excoriated.

Comment: @AndrewRay Two short paragraphs in a longer answer where a method to remove the accents  by just uncommenting a command is suggested. Doesn't seem a “lengthy rant”.

Comment: @AndrewRay We’re a very friendly place. Even if we think something should be excised, I’d hope we wouldn’t excoriate it!

Comment: One minor addendum: as you certainly know, T1 encoding should only be used with PDFLaTeX, and with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, we should `\usepackage{fontspec}` instead. Kind of pedantic, but worth mentioning for any newbie copying-and-pasting the code.

Comment: @AndrewRay - If the publication requires lím (for límite) instead of lim, there is not much that can be done. But does the question indicate that? Anyway, I don't care whether English-speakers use lím or Spanish speakers use lim, but until automatic translation gets much better, using both (let alone hundreds of other variations) seems unhelpful.

Comment: @Davislor - Good point. FWIW, I've recently started to include `\usepackage{iftex} \ifpdftex \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} \else \usepackage{fontspec} \fi` in the preambles of my answers that might include loading the `fontenc` package, to help the noobs with their copying-and-pasting jobs.

Comment: @mico I’d suggest `\iftutex \usepackage{fontspec} \else \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} \fi`. This has better backward and forward compatibility.